# How to animate multi form process with ajax jquery and php?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

Through PHP the steps are counted and added in a session to avoid returning to the beginning in case of updating or refreshing the page, the value is obtained by means of the following variable `$step`

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if ( !empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['__step__'])) {
    $step = $_SESSION['datos_form']['__step__'];
  } else {
    $step = '1';
  }

?>
```

We receive the value of the variable in the jQuery javascript code.

```
show_step(<?= $step; ?>);
```

That would be equal to: (for the default value received)

```
show_step(1);
```

Each step of the process is shown according to the value received from PHP to the Javascript code as it was already mentioned.

Without the need to add additional controls like the following:

```
current = $(this).parent();
next = $(this).parent().next();
```

I have the following simple wizard with CSS

https://jsfiddle.net/2LL8x1sm/

I need to be able to adapt it to the ajax javascript code so that it animates the step in which it is.

The current code already had an animation using a technique called sprite

```
function animacion(caso){}
```

[image]

What I need is to be able to adapt the animation of the process, and using an icon [(like this one)](https://media.dermstore.com/images/style/bootstrap3/img/cart-icon.png) that goes [sliding](https://jsfiddle.net/byuvpL41/) with the bar of progress similar to the following image:

[image]

This animation must be added inside the function `animacion(caso) {}` that works together with the back links and continue, add an example within the fuction in the following code:

```
$( ".test" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
```

And in effect it works, the div with the test class was modifying the left style by continuing in each step.

**How can I animate the process of my html code css?**

```js
$(function() {
    show_step(<?= $step; ?>);        
});

function animacion(caso){
  //$( ".test" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
};

// function to save the form data and change the step
function show_step(step){
    var data = $( "#form" ).serialize();
    var url = 'saveTemp.php?step=' + step;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data
    })
    .done(function( resp ) {
        $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
        $('#step'+step).fadeIn("slow");
        //animation of each step
        animacion(step);
    });
};
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li > * {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #2c3f4c;
  top: -45px;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display: block;
  text-align:  center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #edeff0;
}
  
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #edeff0;
  top: 4px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
  
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
  
.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}
  
.progressbar li.active:before {
  background-color: green;
}
  
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- <div class="test"></div> -->

<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
   <li class="active"><span>Step 1</span></li>
   <li><span>Step 2</span></li>
   <li><span>Step 3</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<form id="form" action="procesar.php">
  <div id="step1" class="step">
   <h1>step 1</h1>
   <a data-ref="#" onclick="show_step(2)">continue</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step2" class="step">
   <h1>step 2</h1>
   <a data-ref="#" onclick="show_step(1)">after</a>
    <a data-ref="#" onclick="show_step(3)">continue</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step3" class="step">
   <h1>step 3</h1>
   <a data-ref="#" onclick="show_step(2)">after</a>
   <button>Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You just neef to animate ?

Comment: @BASEERHAIDERJAFRI 
Yes friend, and if possible an example of how to validate possible forms, to avoid following the next step.

Comment: for form validation use Jquery Validator (https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: @BASEERHAIDERJADRI Ok perfect friend...

Comment: @BASEERHAIDERJAFRI ok then you would help me with the animation of the wizard to know what step the wizard is in, that is, change the animation of the image I already had by the one that is here jsfiddle.net/2LL8x1sm

Comment: do you want bucket in your steps? because i think you already have a green line in your steps and you can simply add class active in your li

Comment: @BASEERHAIDERJAFRI If I already have the design, exactly you only need to add the active class to the li, but I do not really know how to do it because the control of the steps has the function: `function animacion(caso){}`

Comment: @BASEERHAIDERJAFRI 
then conditions must be passed to be able to detect when it continues and when it goes backwards in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this correct understanding of what you need?

```js
function animacion(caso) {
    if (!caso) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("progressbar")[0].setAttribute("data-active", "");
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("progressbar")[0].setAttribute("data-active", caso);
    }
    var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (!caso) {
            item.className = "";
        } else if (i < caso) {
            item.className = "active";
        } else {
            item.className = "";
        }
    }
}

setTimeout(function () {
    animacion(1);
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function () {
    animacion(2);
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function () {
    animacion(3);
}, 3000);
setTimeout(function () {
    animacion(2);
}, 4000);
setTimeout(function () {
    animacion(1);
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function () {
    animacion(null);
}, 6000);
```

```css
.container {
 width: 100%;
}
.progressbar {
 counter-reset: step;

}
.progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 width: 33.33%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li > * {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 color: #2c3f4c;
 top: -45px;
 /* new code start */
 top: -65px;
 /* new code end */
}
.progressbar li:before {
 content: '';
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 display: block;
 text-align:  center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #edeff0;
}
.progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 4px;
 background-color: #edeff0;
 top: 4px;
 left: -50%;
 z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
 content: none;
}
.progressbar li.active {
 color: green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before {
 background-color: green;
 /* new code start */
 -webkit-transition: background 300ms ease;
 transition: background 300ms ease;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
 transition-delay: 300ms;
 /* new code end */
}

/* removed code start */
/*
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
 background-color: green;
}
*/
/* removed code end */

/* new code start */
.progressbar {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.progressbar:after {
 content: "";
 height: 4px;
 left: 16.666%;
 background: green;
 top: 4px;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transition: width 300ms ease;
 transition: width 300ms ease;
}
.progressbar[data-active="1"]:after {
 width: 0;
}
.progressbar[data-active="2"]:after {
 width: 33%;
}
.progressbar[data-active="3"]:after {
 width: 66%;
}
.progressbar[data-active=""]:before {
 opacity: 0;
}
.progressbar:not([data-active=""]):before {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: left 300ms ease, opacity 300ms ease;
 transition: left 300ms ease, opacity 300ms ease;
}
.progressbar[data-active="1"]:before {
 left: 16.666%;
}
.progressbar[data-active="2"]:before {
 left: 50%;
}
.progressbar[data-active="3"]:before {
 left: 83.333%;
}
.progressbar:before {
 content: "";
 height: 16px;
 width: 16px;
 margin-top: -24px;
 margin-left: -8px;
 left: 16.666%;
 background: khaki;
 top: 4px;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transition: left 300ms ease;
 transition: left 300ms ease;
}
/* new code end */
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <ul class="progressbar" data-active="">
        <li><span>Step 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Step 2</span></li>
        <li><span>Step 3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There is minor change in markup and style. Rectange indicates block where you can insert your icons.

Comment: It's great, but it's only in javascript, and my wizard is in jquery + ajax.

Comment: Just put setStep function inside your ajax. Like .done( function(e) { setStep(e) } ) I beleive it will work.

Comment: in this way https://jsfiddle.net/un2n17wj/  it works so well but there update the page so that the changes are seen, you have some idea to add the controls like the link that mentions you.

Comment: Do you mean you need PHP part of the code? In JS you simply use one function. When document is ready you just set step number.

Comment: no, no friend, the code I've linked is code javascript jquery.

Comment: By means of `switch(caso)` it the parameters `(caso)` that are numerical values are recovered, that is, they are the counted steps of the wizard, I do not know if you understand me.

Comment: The code you have linked - I have changed it. Look at my snippet's JS. I have renamed my function so that it is cleanly visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161151/discussion-between-ilya-b-and-gph).